# Is it possible to render igCombo with igUpload

Tags: javascript, infragistics, ignite-ui, igcombo

I want to render `igCombo` against each file when i add them using `igUpload`.

The idea is that when user presses the add button and selects the images, an `igCombo` is rendered in front of each file where the user can put some additional information before uploading them.

Is this possible to be accomplished using `igUpload`?

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy way to achieve this. It will require a lot of custom logic.
Here is what you need to do if you want to try implementing it by yourself:

1. Handle the [igUpload.fileSelected](http://igniteui.com/help/api/2016.2/ui.igupload#events:fileSelected) event and find the DOM node under igUpload widget where you want to put the combo.
2. Insert a new "input" element and instantiate igCombo on it
3. Follow the ["Sending additional data from the client to the server"](http://www.igniteui.com/help/igupload-using-server-side-events) topic to send the data from the combo to the server